# Jquery add css but don´t ovverwrite old value

Tags: jquery

for a little CSS3 font Tester I have several checkboxes to add Opentype stylisticSet features to a textarea. Currentliy I´m doing this by adding a class with jquery like:

```
$( "#fontform" ).addClass( "ss01" );
```

where class looks like:

```
.ss01 {
    -moz-font-feature-settings: "ss01";
    -webkit-font-feature-settings: "ss01";
    font-feature-settings: "ss01";
}
```

The Problem with this is if one clicks the next checkbox f.e. for ss02 the previous value of `font-feature-settings` is overwritten. Is there some way with jquery to add the value like:

```
.appliedstylies {
    -moz-font-feature-settings: "ss01","ss02";
    -webkit-font-feature-settings: "ss01","ss02";
    font-feature-settings: "ss01","ss02";
}
```

thanks!

Comment: So you want to have both styles applied and only it would be a mix of both styles? Or you want only that first style to show?

Comment: Will updating/adding individual style elements via `.css()` work for you?

Comment: This is more of a CSS question than jquery...

Comment: @ ntgCleaner yes right it should be a mix of box styles. It should most likely work to add/edit an inline style to the element like `style="font-feature-settings: "ss01","ss02";"` but most likely I would have to write some regex for it. Maybe there is some simpler way with jquery?

Comment: S.Kiers I don´t think so as the main question is how to modify the dom

Comment: could you do `.attr('style', '-moz-font-feature-settings: "ss01", "ss02"');` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this if you want to toggle options.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var array = [];
  
  $(".btn").click(function() {
    var data = "'" + $(this).data("value") + "'",
        index = array.indexOf(data),
        style_value;
    
    if (index == -1) {
      array.push(data);
    } else {
      array.splice(index, 1);
    }

    if (array.length > 0) {
    style_value = array.join(",");
      $("#target").attr('style',
        "-moz-font-feature-settings:" + style_value + ";" +
        "-webkit-font-feature-settings:" + style_value + ";" +
        "font-feature-settings:" + style_value ) + ";"
    } else {
      $("#target").attr('style','');
    }
    $('#target span').html($('#target').attr('style'))
    console.log(index)
    console.log(data)
    console.log(array)
    console.log(style_value)
    
  });
});
```

```css
#target {
  border:1px dotted yellow;
  padding:5px;
  background:lightyellow;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
#target span {
  display:block;
  font-size:13px;
  font-family:Consolas,Menlo,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New,monospace,sans-serif;
  color:#222;
  }
.btn
{
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  padding:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  background: #eee;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="target">Style: <span></span></div>

<div class="btn" data-value="ss01">ss01</div>
<div class="btn" data-value="ss02">ss02</div>
<div class="btn" data-value="ss03">ss03</div>
```

Comment: Should probably be optimized, I made it quite verbose to be easier to follow.

Answer (score 0):

You could try appending the class if it is not found already in the class list for `font-feature-settings`:

```
function appendClass(c){
    var styles = $('#fontform').css('font-feature-settings');
    //Check for class in current setting
    if(styles && !styles.contains(c)){
        styles += ',"' + c + '"';
        $('#fontform').css({
            'font-feature-settings': styles,
            '-moz-font-feature-settings': styles,
            '-webkit-font-feature-settings': styles
        });
    }
}
```